# we detected a login into your account from a new device named: uiwebview

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

We are using Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1 and when we connect to Facebook using a UIWebView we receive the following message via e-mail:

Hi Sei,
We detected a login into your account from a new device named "UIWebView on iPod" on Wednesday, May 8, 2013 at 8:59pm. This device has been added to your account.

Operating System: iOS

Browser: UIWebView

Location: Mountain View, CA, US

Note: Location is based on internet service provider information.
If this was you, please disregard this email.
If this wasn't you, please secure your account, as someone else may be accessing it.
Thanks,
The Facebook Security Team

Is it possible (in objective c, through code) to change the device name from UIWebView to something more meaningful?

Thank you

Comment: Just received a reply from Facebook basically claiming that this is not an issue. Not sure many users understand what UIWebView is. => The bug you are subscribed to "We detected a login into your account from a new device named "UIWebView on iPod"" has been updated:
Status has changed: New → By Design
This is by design as of now. We can reconsider changing this in future.

Comment: Dear, did you find solution? I have same problem.

Comment: Did you guys hear of any solution @Alex?

Comment: Did you hear of any solution @user2365068?

Comment: @user2365068 do you have the bugID of this issue?